# Create an Updatable Model - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, model, entity

I just want to know if there's a way on how to create an Updatable model. Right now, I have to create procedures for insert, update, and delete for all of the tables in my model. This is very tedious so I was wondering if there is one way which I could do to resolve this?

I remember before in my previous work that we used to make models and access them (CRUD) without creating procedures. But i'm not really certain now on how it was made.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways in which you can automate the generation (on the fly or already generated at compile time) of the actual SQL calls to the database to insert, select, update and delete within the Entity Framework.

1. You can use the ORM tools (e.g. Linq to Entities) to minimise or eliminate the writing of raw SQL. This means you still have to use the correct attributes on your entities and the properties/methods therein and that's a manual process. (Some backgrounding on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx))
2. You can allow the framework to automatically generate your entities based on some existing database schema (only possible with SqlServer-type databases) which basically does 90% of the work for you. There may be some cases where you need to override, for example, the default insert SQL with something custom. This is achieved via the [Generate Database Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456817.aspx) (which I think is a part of Visual Studio 2008+).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `POCO` classes with EF. If you're using 4.1 and above, you can use the [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class. To map your model to the table / columns, simply override `OnModelCreating` in your context class (which inherits from `DbContext`). Say you have a model called `User`, a table called `Users`, and the context class `MyContext`, the code could be smth like this:

```
public class User
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public MyContext() :
    base("MyContext")
  {
  }

  public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
      .ToTable("Users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
      .Property(d => d.UserId)
      .HasColumnName("UserId")
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
      .Property(d => d.UserName)
      .HasColumnName("UserName");
  }    

}
```

To use it, simply add the `User` instance to your `DbSet`, then call `SaveChanges`:

```
using(MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
  var u = new User() { UserId = 1, UserName = "A" };
  ctx.Users.Add(u);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```